# Young modulus and Sound Velocity in a continuus medium

Tags: elasticity

In elasticity theory, general equations of motion are:

$$\rho \partial^2_t \overline{u} = \mu \nabla^2 \overline{u} + (\mu+\lambda) \nabla(\nabla \cdot \overline{u})$$

where $\overline u$ are displacements.

In a thin homogeneus rod with tractions and compressions in the x direction, stress tensor $S_{ij}$ is:
$$ \pmatrix{
S_{xx} &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 \\} $$
Young modulus is:
$$ E=\frac{S_{xx}}{\epsilon_{11}}=\frac{\lambda+\mu}{\mu(3\lambda+2\mu)} 
$$
where $\epsilon_{11}=\partial_x u_x$ is the deformation on x

So equation of motion for x-displacements is:
$$
\rho \partial^2_t u_x=\partial_x S_{xx}= E \partial^2_x u_x= \frac{\lambda+\mu}{\mu(3\lambda+2\mu)} \partial^2_x u_x
$$

Why is this different to the result of general equation of motion with only dependence to x:
$$
\rho \partial^2_t u_x=(2\mu+\lambda)\partial^2_x u_x
$$
?

Or: why in a elastic rod has the sound smaller speed than in a generic homogeneus indefinite medium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check your math. Correct derivation is

$$\begin{eqnarray}
{f \over \epsilon_{11}} & = & {S_{11} \over \epsilon_{11}}=(2\mu+\lambda)+\lambda {\epsilon_{22}+\epsilon_{33} \over \epsilon_{11}} = \\
& = & (2\mu+\lambda)-{\lambda^2 \over \lambda + \mu} = {(2\mu + \lambda)(\lambda + \mu) - \lambda^2 \over \lambda + \mu}=\frac{\mu(3\lambda+2\mu)}{\lambda+\mu} 
\end{eqnarray}$$

And this is precisely what Young modulus is defined to be (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus)).

Comment: sorry, I'm stupid! Thank you!Now I'll write the most important question I'll change the question with my real doubt. I thought it was the reason, but it isn't ...

Comment: @Boy: no problem. Feel feel to change the question, I'll update my answer as necessary.

Comment: @Boy Well, it is a better idea to make a new question.